# Getting error Operand should countain 1 Column(s);

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im trying to get the id ,feename from 1 table id is not in studentfeeTable where invoiceID is 5 but i Got this error. I dont know how to deal with it. please help

```
select id, Fee_Head_Name from admission_fees_structure Where ID NOT IN (Select * from 
student_fee_detail where invoiceID=5) ;
```

Comment: it is wiser to use 'id' on your subquery rather than '*' because youre returning different kinds of result rathen than the ID youre looking for

Answer (score 3):

You have used "ID NOT IN (Select * from  student_fee_detail where invoiceID=5)".

You should use "ID NOT IN (Select ID from student_fee_detail where invoiceID=5)".

You should compare one column with other. not entire row.

Its better to use exist in this scenario.

```
select id, Fee_Head_Name 
FROM admission_fees_structure outer 
Where 
exists 
(Select 1 from Student_fee_detail inner 
where inner.invoiceID=5 and inner.ID = outer.ID) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Sub query you must select Id not the '*' because you are comparing it with the ID. You cannot compare a single column with the entire row. how would MySQl know that which value in the entire row is to compare with the ID.
it must be like this

`Select Id from 
student_fee_detail where invoiceID=5`